# Adding Spatial Analyst to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, installation

I am using an off-campus computer and need to add the Spatial Analyst to ArcMap in ArcGIS for Desktop.

Could someone please give step-by-step instructions on the order I need to install this?

Comment: Do you have a license for the Spatial Analyst extension?

Comment: There is no separate installation (hasn't been for a *long* time now), but you do need to select the correct modules during installation (or alter the install to add them, afterward).  This is adequately covered by the installation documentation.

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to requests for clarification.  Do not add Answers to respond to comments. The [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help) are useful in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

As Vince commented, there is not a separate install for Spatial Analyst anymore.  But what you will need to do (**when you are on campus or on a network where you can reach the license server**) is listed below. You will have to check out a license for both ArcMap and the Spatial Analyst Extension (and any other extensions you may want to utilize away from the license server).

> Borrowing licenses
>
> 1. Using the ArcGIS Administrator, select the desired product folder
>    (Desktop or Engine) in the table of contents for which you want to
>    borrow licenses.
> 2. Make sure the license manager has been defined.
> 3. Select the Borrow/Return folder. Set the number of days you want to
>    borrow licenses for in the Borrow For: box.
> 4. Check the boxes of the
>    features you want to borrow and click Apply.
> 5. After the licenses have
>    been borrowed, click OK to close the ArcGIS Administrator.
> 6. You can now
>    use your ArcGIS software while off the network.

See: [ESRI Help Link on Borrowing Licenses](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/administering-desktop/borrowing-and-returning-licenses.htm)